# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 – Need to have Subgrid Lookup Filter

Tags: dynamics-crm

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 – 
Need to filter the look up on a subgrid
Javascript code I am using:

```
function SetCustomLookUp() {
    debugger;
    lookupFieldObject = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('account');
    if (lookupFieldObject.getValue() != null) {
        entityId = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].id;
        entityName = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].entityType;
        entityLabel = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].name;
    }

    var filterXML = [
            '<filter type="and">',
            '<condition attribute="parentcustomerid" value="{54BC1539-C29C-E511-80E9-3863BB2E6258}" operator="eq"/>',
            '</filter>'
        ].join('\n');
var Subgrid = Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts");
    document.getElementById("Contacts").addEventListener("click", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var gridControl = Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts");
            var me = gridControl.$c_0.$N_4.$Y_3;
            me.addPreSearch(function () {
                me.addCustomFilter(filterXML);
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Error: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: You are using unsupported code so you probably shouldn't expect this to work. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks James.. Here is my requirement-I have a custom entity- Call Report. It has N:N relation with Contacts.Now the sub grid of contacts on call report has a look up of contacts which by default shows all the contacts.I need to filter this look up to show only particular contacts and not all.Using CRM 2015 online

Comment: This isnt clear, are you trying to filter a sub grid or a lookup?

Comment: Its look up of contacts in a subgrid. Need to filter the look up inside the grid.

Comment: Are you referring to the lookup that comes up when you click the + button?  If so, you could try setting the grid to show the view selector and then using the `setCurrentView` api method to set the view of the grid to some view that does your filtering, and then seeing if the + button defaults to the view you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and erro thet you present, the reason is:

the subgrid is painting at the end of paint all form, and then you must add this even of click when the sub-grid is painting

I write a small code for this:

```
var objSubGrid = document.getElementById("subgrid_name");

//CRM loads subgrid after form is loaded.. so when we are adding script on form load.. need to wait until sub grid is loaded. 
// that's why we are adding a delay..
if (objSubGrid == null) {
    setTimeout(functionxxx, 2000);
    return;
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Following article contains answer - http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2016/06/20/filter-n-n-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2016-turbo-forms

To Modarators - Yes, I know that it is recommended to retype everything that is mentioned in article but I'm pretty sure that article will be available online for a long time so I just will not retype because it has no sense for me.